# Plotting Maxwellian Distribution in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a list of positive and negative values and a single temperature. I am trying to plot the [Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution#Derivation_and_related_distributions) using the equation for particles moving in only one direction.

```
m_e = 9.11E-28 # electron mass [g]
k = 1.38E-16 # boltzmann constant [erg*K^-1]
v = range(1e10, -1e10, step=-1e8) # velocity [cm/s]

T_M = 1e6 # temperature of Maxwellian [K]

function Maxwellian(v_Max, T_Max)
    normal = (m_e/(2*pi*k*T_Max))^1.5
    exp_term = exp(-((m_e).*v_Max.*v_Max)/(3*k*T_Max))
    return normal*exp_term
end

# Initially comparing chosen distribution f_s to Maxwellian F_s
plot(v, Maxwellian.(v, T_M), label= L"F_s" * " (Maxwellian)")
xlabel!("velocity (cm/s)")
ylabel!("probability density")
```

However, when, plotting this, my whole function is 0:

[image]

I tested out if I wrote my function correctly by replacing `return normal*exp_term` with `return exp_term` (i.e. ignoring any normalization constants) and this seems to produce the distinct of the bell curve:

[image]

Yet, without the normalization constant, this will not preserve the area under the curve. I was wondering what may I be doing incorrectly with setting up my Maxwellian function and the constant in front of the exponential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print the normalization term on its own:

```
julia> (m_e/(2*pi*k*T_M))^1.5
1.0769341115495682e-27
```

you can see that it is 10 orders of magnitude smaller than the Y-axis scale used for the plot. You can set the Y-axis limits during the plots with `ylims` argument, or after the plot with:

```
julia> ylims!(-1e-28, 2e-27)
```

which changes the plot to:

[image: Bell type curve]